# Переписать цикл с помощью Stream Api

Tags: java, java-stream

Можно ли переписать этот код с помощью Stream Api, как это будет выглядеть?

```
    Set<ContactGroup> groups = user.getGroups();
    Set<String> groupNames = new HashSet<>(); 
    for (ContactGroup group :
            groups) {
        groupNames.add(group.getName());
    }
```

Comment: что-то вроде `groups.stream().map(g->g.getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<String> groupNames = user.getGroups()
                             .stream()
                             .map(ContactGroup::getName)
                             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```